# How to delete item/file from a listView and external SD?

Tags: file, listview, delete-file

I'm new to Java and coding all together so I have hit a wall with my code. I've read nearly every post on this subject and still can't grasp it. Can somebody help?

Here is my code and permissions are already set in the manifest. Basically when I try to delete an item/file from a listview using onLongClick a file deletes, just not the one I want. The item first on the list deletes every attempt. I'm not sure how to solve this. I know that the code is half right considering the file does delete from the directory on the SD and from the listview. Getting the right file to delete is the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class ReadNoteMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.m4tchb0x87.rhinote.MESSAGE";

Context context;

public ReadNoteMenu() {

    this.context = this;
}

ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter;
ListView listView;


protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_note_menu);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.readListView);
    String fileNames[] = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()) + "/Rhinote").list();
    mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_item_1, fileNames);
    listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String string = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ReadNoteMenu.this, (Class) ReadNote.class);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, string);
            ReadNoteMenu.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {


        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView adapterView, final View view, int position, long l) {

            ContextThemeWrapper CTW = new ContextThemeWrapper( context, R.style.ADM_theme);
            MaterialDialogCompat.Builder MDM1 = new MaterialDialogCompat.Builder(CTW);

            MDM1.setMessage("Edit or delete file?");
            MDM1.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,  int i) {

                    ContextThemeWrapper CTW = new ContextThemeWrapper( context, R.style.ADM_theme);
                    MaterialDialogCompat.Builder MDM2 = new MaterialDialogCompat.Builder(CTW);



                    MDM2.setMessage("Confirm delete file?");
                    MDM2.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {






                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {


                            String str = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                            Log.d(str,"Deleted" );

                            new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/RhiNote" + "/" + str).delete();

                            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_deleted,
                                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root_deleted));
                            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text_deleted);
                            text.setText("Note deleted!");
                            Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 250, 25);
                            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.setView(layout);
                            toast.show();

                            ReadNoteMenu.this.finish();
                            ReadNoteMenu.this.startActivity(ReadNoteMenu.this.getIntent());

                        }
                    });

                    MDM2.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {

                            ReadNoteMenu.this.startActivity(ReadNoteMenu.this.getIntent());
                        }
                    });

                    MDM2.show();

                }
            });


            MDM1.setNegativeButton("Edit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {

                    ReadNoteMenu.this.startActivity(ReadNoteMenu.this.getIntent());

                }
            });

            MDM1.show();


            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I figured out where I went wrong after a little debugging. It seems that the problem was that I hadn't declared the onItemLongClick int position final.

```
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView adapterView, final View view, final int position, long l)
```